# Freenom A Record

Tags: dns

I want to publish a Google Site using a free domain.

I used the domain `.cf` in Freenom and followed the steps given by them. Then they said to click on "Manage DNS record".

What should I put in the "Name" and "Target" fields?

It is showing

> Error: Invalid value in DNS record

[image: DNS Management]

Answer (score 0):

You can put * for Name and your Google Site page in the Target.

This would make all requests to be forwarded to your Google Site page.